# Plotting standard deviation as normalized

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, visualization

So I do this simulation, I get an estimate of a value y, then repeat the simulation and get the mean of that value and its standard deviation. Now I already have an expected value of that y, when plotting the bias or error as "Estimated value - Expected value", is it correct to plot the standard deviation as it is in errorbars or do I have to scale or normalize it by some factor.

Is it correct to use y_sd just as it is, even though the y axis isn't the mean values of y but the bias?
What if the bias or error is relative, i.e. "(Estimated value- Expected value)/Expected value", what is the scaling then?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x=np.linspace(1,10,10) 
y=np.linspace(1,10,10) # mean estimated values
y_sd =np.random.normal(0, 1, 10) # standard deviation of estimated values
y_expected = np.linspace(2,20,10) # expected values of y
bias = y-y_expected 
plt.errorbars(x,bias,yerr=y_sd)
plt.show()
```